# Dynamically create print statement in Java

Tags: java, database

I query a database and get a lot information back that should be presented to the user. In the database I have fields a, b, c, d and e. Now, the user should be able to indicate which of these fields that should be printed on screen (i.e. the user can choose to view only a subset of the data retrieved from the database).

How do I dynamically create a print statement that sometimes prints two of the fields, sometimes four, sometimes three etc. depending on what the user wants?

Comment: I'm not a java guy, but I guess you're over-complicating the problem !

Comment: Are you talking about printing these to the screen? Like Tarun stated, I think you are over-complicating this.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about printing to the screen. There should be one column for each field in the database. But the user should be able to "filter" the data and say that he is only interested in certain columns. Then only those should be printed.

Answer (score 0):

If all the hard work is already done and you just have a result set to print, then it could be as simple as a succession of calls to `System.out.print()` for each result and then finish the line with a `\n`. It can be nested in a FOR loop, so if you have an `int` with the number of fields to print, just iterate through them.

In a more complicated case when you have a full list where some fields are chosen and others not, then you could use a (slightly) crude method like this:

```
...

String[] chosenFields = {"Field 1", "Field 2" /*, (et cetera) */};

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFields; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < chosenFields.length; j++)
    {
        if (fieldsName[i].equals(chosenFields[j]))
            System.out.print(fields[i] + " ");

        break;
    }
}

System.out.println();

...
```

Sorry about bad indentation; not sure how to sort it on here!

If field names are indeterminate at runtime and you're using Java to execute queries, consider using class `ResultSetMetaData` to get them.

EDIT:

As an example, here's some of my code which gets all the field names from a table, then creates a tickbox for each, which the user can select or deselect. All the JFrame GUI stuff I've omitted. When the user presses a submit button, the application check each tickbox and constructs an SQL statement to suit the users request.

```
...

JCheckBox[] jcb;
ResultSetMetaData rsmd;

    private void makeCheckBoxes()
{
    initConnection(); // Establish connection to MySQL server

    try
    {
        Statement query = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM client_db;");
        rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        noOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        jcb = new JCheckBox[noOfColumns];

        for (int i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i++)
        {
            jcb[i] = new JCheckBox(rsmd.getColumnName(i + 1));
            jpCheckBoxes.add(jcb[i]);
            jcb[i].setEnabled(false);
            jcbComboBox.addItem(rsmd.getColumnName(i + 1));
        }

        jcb[0].setSelected(true);

        rs.close();
        query.close();

        connection.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.err.println("!> Caught SQLException:\n" + e.getMessage());

        System.exit(1);
    }
}

...
if (e.getSource() == jbSubmit)
    {
        String query = "";

        initConnection();

        if (jtfSearch.getText().isEmpty() == true) // JTextField
        {
            jtaResults.setText(null); // JTextArea
            jtaResults.append("Please enter some search text in the text box above!\n");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int selectedFields;

            if (jrbAll.isSelected() == true) // JRadioButton
            {
                query = "SELECT *";

                selectedFields = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                query = "SELECT";
                selectedFields = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i++)
                    if (jcb[i].isSelected() == true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (selectedFields > 0)
                                query += ",";

                            query += " " + rsmd.getColumnName(i + 1);
                        }
                        catch (SQLException err)
                        {
                            System.err.println("!> Caught SQLException:\n" + err.getMessage());

                            System.exit(1);
                        }

                        selectedFields++;
                    }
                }

            if (selectedFields == 0)
            {
                jtaResults.setText(null);
                jtaResults.append("No fields were selected!!\n");

                return;
            }
            else
            {
                query += " FROM client_db WHERE " + jcbComboBox.getSelectedItem() + " LIKE '%" + jtfSearch.getText() + "%'";

                if (jcbCurrentClients.isSelected() == true)
                    query += " AND currentClient LIKE 'y'";

                query += ";";
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Query = \"" + query + "\"");

        /* Now, print it out in the text area!! */

        try
        {
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();

            int columnCount = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();
            jtaResults.append("--------------------------------\n");
            int noOfResults = 0;

            jtaResults.setText(null);

            while (rs.next() == true)
            {
                if (noOfResults > 0)
                    jtaResults.append("\n");

                jtaResults.append("* Search match " + (noOfResults + 1) + ":\n");

                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                {
                    jtaResults.append("-> " + rsMetaData.getColumnName(i + 1) + ": " +
                                            rs.getString(i + 1) + "\n");
                }

                noOfResults++;
            }

            if (noOfResults == 0)
            {
                jtaResults.append("No results were returned; please try again with more ambiguous search terms.\n\n");
            }

            //scroller.setScrollPosition(0, 1048576);

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();

            connection.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException err)
        {
            System.err.println("!> Caught SQLException:\n" + err.getMessage());

            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps. The sustained concatenation to `query` forms a valid SQL statement based on the fields the user chose. Hopefully a few modifications to this to just print certain fields will help you. The `System.out.println()` call to print `query` about two-thirds down is a good place to work from.

Comment: By the way, I'm assuming when you want to create a varied-length print statement, all you mean is printing a variable amount of data to one line?

Answer (score 0):

The natural way to switch an optional value on or off would be a radiobutton. For 5 fields i.e. an array of 5 radiobuttons.

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer (5 * 10);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    if (rb[i])
        s.append (field[i]).append (" ");
```

Maybe you're better of only selecting interesting columns from the database? Then a dummy-column is helpful:

```
sql = new StringBuffer ("SELECT 1 "); // the dummy-column
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    if (rb[i])
        sql.append (", ").append (fieldname[i]);
```